# My flutter app is not getting data from http after build release apk

Tags: flutter

My flutter application is not getting data from http after build release apk. But everything is OK in build debug mode. There is no problem on my code since it is loading the data from http in build debug mode.

Can any one tell me what did I miss.

Comment: You can check "Run Release Model" in Run Menu and check what error it is showing?

Comment: There is no error. Just it is not loading the data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

give permission of `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your android Manifest file.

then try again to build apk