# How to solve showing loading only in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter. When I use `flutter run`,there are no errors and I can see all the things in my apps. But after I build the apk, it only show loading . Can I know how to solve it?

Comment: did your app use internet?

Comment: yes, My app have use internet

Comment: have you add permission to access internet in **manifest** file of android?

Comment: After I add it can already. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flutter is not automatic add that permission.

so at the time of building app for release you must add dependancy for **Internet**

[you can follow my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083080/my-flutter-app-is-not-getting-data-from-http-after-build-release-apk/59083443#59083443)